# Xcode 10.1 crashes on open due to detailAccentColor unrecognised

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-mojave

So today while opening Xcode (Version 10.1 (10B61)) it installed some additional packages (unfortunately I don't know what). Then when it came to opening anything (existing project, creating a new project, creating playground) it crashed with error as posted below.

I tried reinstalling Xcode, but the same error occurred.
I'm using MacOS Mojave (version 10.14 (18A314k))

And finally an error:

```
Process:               Xcode [2163]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               10.1 (14460.46)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks_Fall2018-14460046000000000~5
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       828917606
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [2163]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2018-11-09 10:45:32.879 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14 (18A314k)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     3.0 (14Y664)
Anonymous UUID:        4A06F9DE-9B81-BB53-A130-5A43E3077DDF


Time Awake Since Boot: 5700 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
Sending newPlayground: to <IDEApplicationCommands: 0x7ffea209fb20> from (null)
ProductBuildVersion: 10B61
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): +[NSColor detailAccentColor]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x7fff9fa73e28
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: 
  0: Sending newPlayground: to <IDEApplicationCommands: 0x7ffea209fb20> from (null)
  1: Sending createNewPlayground: to <IDEWelcomeWindowController: 0x7ffea123e380> from <IDEWelcomeWindowHighlightButton: 0x7ffea13f21a0>
Backtrace:
  0   __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1   DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2   objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3   +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] (in CoreFoundation)
  4   ___forwarding___ (in CoreFoundation)
  5   _CF_forwarding_prep_0 (in CoreFoundation)
  6   -[DVTTheme activityViewDeterminateProgessIndicatorColor] (in DVTKit)
  7   -[IDEActivityProgressIndicatorLayer _updateProgressLayerColor] (in IDEKit)
  8   -[IDEActivityProgressIndicatorLayer reflectStyle] (in IDEKit)
  9   -[IDEActivityProgressIndicatorLayer setupLayers] (in IDEKit)
 10   -[IDEActivityProgressIndicatorLayer init] (in IDEKit)
 11   -[IDEActivityReportLayer init] (in IDEKit)
 12   +[IDEActivityReportLayer activityReportLayerForDisplayStyle:] (in IDEKit)
 13   -[IDEActivityView _buildReportLayerTree] (in IDEKit)
 14   -[IDEActivityView setupLayers] (in IDEKit)
 15   -[IDEActivityView setup] (in IDEKit)
 16   -[IDEActivityView setupOrTearDown] (in IDEKit)
 17   -[NSView _setWindow:] (in AppKit)
 18   -[NSView addSubview:] (in AppKit)
 19   -[NSToolbarItemViewer configureForLayoutInDisplayMode:andSizeMode:inToolbarView:] (in AppKit)
 20   -[NSToolbarView _layoutDirtyItemViewersAndTileToolbar] (in AppKit)
 21   -[NSToolbarView _syncItemSetAndUpdateItemViewersWithSEL:setNeedsModeConfiguration:sizeToFit:setNeedsDisplay:updateKeyLoop:] (in AppKit)
 22   -[NSToolbarView _noteToolbarLayoutChanged] (in AppKit)
 23   -[NSView _setWindow:] (in AppKit)
 24   -[NSView addSubview:] (in AppKit)
 25   -[NSTitlebarView addSubview:] (in AppKit)
 26   -[NSThemeFrame addTitlebarSubview:] (in AppKit)
 27   -[NSThemeFrame _showHideToolbar:resizeWindow:animate:] (in AppKit)
 28   -[NSWindow _showToolbar:animate:] (in AppKit)
 29   -[NSToolbar _show:animate:] (in AppKit)
 30   -[NSWindow setToolbar:] (in AppKit)
 31   -[NSWindow(IBNSToolbarFixes) ibSwizzledSetToolbar:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration)
 32   +[IDEToolbarManager insertToolbarForToolbarDefinitionIdentifier:inWindow:] (in IDEKit)
 33   __45-[IDEWorkspaceWindowController windowDidLoad]_block_invoke (in IDEKit)
 34   -[NSObject(DVTObservingConvenience) _dvt_newObserverForKeyPath:options:owner:creationBacktrace:withHandlerBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
 35   -[NSObject(DVTObservingConvenience) dvt_newObserverForKeyPath:options:withHandlerBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
 36   -[IDEWorkspaceWindowController windowDidLoad] (in IDEKit)
 37   -[NSWindowController _windowDidLoad] (in AppKit)
 38   -[NSWindowController window] (in AppKit)
 39   -[IDEDocumentController _openUntitledWorkspaceDocumentAndDisplay:simpleFilesFocused:forSingleFile:editorDocumentURLOrNil:error:] (in IDEKit)
 40   -[IDEApplicationCommands newTemplateForTemplateKind:template:] (in IDEKit)
 41   -[IDEApplicationCommands newTemplateSkippingChooserIfPossibleForTemplateKind:] (in IDEKit)
 42   -[IDEApplicationCommands newPlayground:] (in IDEKit)
 43   -[NSApplication(NSResponder) sendAction:to:from:] (in AppKit)
 44   __37-[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:]_block_invoke.99 (in DVTKit)
 45   DVTInvokeWithFailureHint (in DVTFoundation)
 46   -[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in DVTKit)
 47   +[IDECommandManager sendActionForCommandWithIdentifier:from:] (in IDEKit)
 48   -[NSApplication(NSResponder) sendAction:to:from:] (in AppKit)
 49   __37-[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:]_block_invoke.99 (in DVTKit)
 50   DVTInvokeWithFailureHint (in DVTFoundation)
 51   -[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in DVTKit)
 52   -[NSControl sendAction:to:] (in AppKit)
 53   __26-[NSCell _sendActionFrom:]_block_invoke (in AppKit)
 54   -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] (in AppKit)
 55   -[NSButtonCell _sendActionFrom:] (in AppKit)
 56   -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] (in AppKit)
 57   -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] (in AppKit)
 58   -[NSControl mouseDown:] (in AppKit)
 59   -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] (in AppKit)
 60   -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] (in AppKit)
 61   -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
 62   -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
 63   -[IDEApplication sendEvent:] (in IDEKit)
 64   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 65   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 66   main (in Xcode)
 67   start (in libdyld.dylib)

abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
NSInvalidArgumentException
```

Comment: This seems to be an internal exception (btw the crash is due to `+detailAccentColor` which seems to be unrecognised (although it [seems that is a valid internal method on Mojave](https://github.com/w0lfschild/macOS_headers/blob/master/macOS/Frameworks/AppKit/1670/NSDynamicSystemColor.h)) and not by a null userInfo). I guess the one thing you could try to do is update your OS (the most recent version at this time is 10.14.1) and see if the problem is fixed, or contact Apple via the bugreporter and hope for a solution.

Comment: I don't know why but 10.14.1 wasn't available from my Mac, I downloaded it from developers page at it solved a problem. Thank you!

Comment: Glad that helped :) I guess we could keep the question open for now in case others have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, It's crashing on launch of Xcode App after that I updated the OS to the latest version.

Due to below issue

```
+[NSColor detailAccentColor]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x7fff9fa73e28
```

Download the latest OS from below link

https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/macos-mojave/id1398502828?mt=12